# Jenkins - Env Inject - Changing .properties file used in my project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

How to inject environmental variables from jenkins

Following is the structure of my automation.properties file of my maven project (test-ng). I have placed the same in config folder of my project workspace.

```
BASEURL = http://uat.myportal.com/
BROWSER   = firefox
GETDBVERSION=Y

TESTDATA = InputTestData/InputData.xlsx
GEOMCHECKDATA = InputTestData/Geometry_Check.xlsx
C_TESTDATA = InputTestData/C_TESTDATA.xlsm
D_TESTDATA = InputTestData/D_TESTDATA.xlsm
```

I then retrieving all properties and add it to a global variables as shown below:

```
public void StoreAllConfigProptoConstants() throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("config/automation.properties");
    CONFIG = new Properties();
    CONFIG.load(fs);

    Constants.URL = CONFIG.getProperty("BASEURL").trim();
    Constants.TESTDATA = CONFIG.getProperty("TESTDATA").trim();
    Constants.GETDBVERSION= CONFIG.getProperty("GETDBVERSION").trim();
     ....
     ....
}
```

when I integrate my project with jenkins, I couldnt change these envrionmental variables.

Can any one help me in doing the same. I tried with envInject but it doesnt seems to be working.

I have tried all combination but it is picking up from the location only but not from jenkins ..

I am new to jenkins and I need experts help in resolving the same. All I need to do is that, I should be able to change during local execution as well as duing jenkins execution.

Explanation with screenshots(if possible) will really help me.

Attaching Screenshot of my Jenkins Setup

[Jenkins set up 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAmMh.jpg)
[Jenkins Set up 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH1fJ.jpg)

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by "I couldnt change these envrionmental variables."  What is expected? What is the actual result?

Comment: Hi Andre, When I execute it locally(not via jenkins), I am able to change the environmental properties and the same has been reflected during execution. But When I invoke it using jenkins , I couldn't change the env parameter(even if I use ENV Inject Plugin). All I need is that I should be able to change environmental parameters via jenkins as well.

Comment: Your code is reading a properties file. Are you generating a properties file in Jenkins using EnvInject? Please give detailed Jenkins config, detailed results, logs.

Comment: @Andre, I am using ENV inject plugin. But I am not sure why the properties file is not getting updated/not picking values from jenkins configurations but my jenkins log clearly shows that it ENV injected successfully. Should I make any changes to code to make it happen / am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Andre, I have added the jenkins configuration as images(links). Please refer to the screenshots - (Jenkins set up 1 and Jenkins Set up 2) under my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is reading `conf/automation.properties` file. This file must exist in your Jenkins job $WORKSPACE/ directory.

Env Inject will *not* replace values in this file.

Env Inject will create environment variables from a file if you give it the file path (which you have done).
Env Inject will create environment variables from anything in Properties Content (which you have done).

Either change your logic to read environment variables instead of a properties file, or provide the desired properties file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am able to understand the context but stuck while implementing the same. Can you please provide steps , pseudo code and screenshots which will help me to understand better.